# What bytes to use in String initialization with data using utf16BigEndian to return nil?

Tags: swift, character-encoding

I know that `String(data:encoding:)` is a failable initializer. 
I have created a function which accepts data as parameter and throws error if a string cannot be created from the data using encoding as utf16BigEndian. It is as below:

```
func createUTF16BEString(data: Data) throws -> String {
    guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf16BigEndian) else {
        throw NSError(domain:"MyAppDomain", code: 33, userInfo: nil)
    }
    return string
}
```

I am writing tests for this function to cover the possibilities of success as well as failure(where an error is thrown).

I have a limited understanding of the encodings for now.

I have written tests which work for successful return of a string.

My problem is what data to pass in(or say bytes) so my tests cover the case where an error would be thrown by my `func createUTF16BEString(data:)` as a result of `String(data:encoding:)` returning nil.

Please suggests me what data should be passed or enhance my knowledge about encodings(so I could figure the bytes) to cover the test mentioned above.

Comment: The conversion from utf16BigEndian data seems to be very lenient, I haven't found an example where it fails so far. Unpaired surrogates are replaced by 0xFFFD (the “replacement character”), and for data with an odd length the final byte is simply ignored.

Comment: Yes I tried using bytes with odd length and it ignored the final byte. Its such a trivial yet hard task to achieve. My code might deal with bytes coming in from random sources over the network. With such incoming of bytes it is bound to fail and needs to be handled gracefully. So I need to be sure that this scenario is taken care of.

Comment: What do you mean by Unpaired surrogates?

Comment: Unicode code points U+010000 to U+10FFFF are represented in UTF-16 as a “surrogate pair”: a “high surrogate” (0xD800–0xDBFF) followed by a “low surrogate” (0xDC00–0xDFFF), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF. – So `Data([0xDB, 0xFF])` would be UTF-16 with an unpaired surrogate: a high surrogate not followed by a low surrogate. But `String(data: data, encoding: .utf16BigEndian)` accepts that and returns `"\u{FFFD}"`. The only thing I can currently think of is to add a check `guard string.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy( { $0.value != 0xFFFD })` to your conversion function.

Comment: Thanks. I will spend some time reading the wiki reference cited by you.